# Unable to connect to Azure DevOps account through Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-devops

I could connect to the Azure DevOps and the Organization through the browser, however if i browse through My Profile page it does not show up the access to the Organization that i have. 
Also it does not list out the organizations while connecting to the Projects from Visual Studio.
Need advice on what has gone wrong.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the access to login on organization? You can add some screen shot to make your question more clear?

Comment: Yes i do have access to login to organization and i have been added to the admin group. I have added the screenshot for your reference.

Comment: @Syed Did your organization connect to the Azure AD? Did you use a Microsoft account or a Azure AD account? Is the directory on this page the same as the Azure AD that your organization connect?